# OpenXML парсинг даты

Tags: c#, openxml

Есть ячейка в документе Excell. В ней дата. Значение ячейки 43017.559872685182

Если открыть документ в программе Excell и посмотреть формат этой ячейки, там будет Дата. НО!

`cell.DataType` при этом равен null. Мои поиски привели меня к информации, что `cell.DataType` не равен null только если это `SharedString` или `Boolean`. Дальше нужно смотреть на `cell.StyleIndex.Value`

Из него вычисляется формат

```
CellFormat cellFormat = (CellFormat)wbPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.ElementAt((int)cellStyle);
```

Так же я нашел описание форматов. (ссылку не помню, но вот на память несколько значений)

14 - короткая дата
165 - длинная дата
164 - денежный (Currency)

А у меня получается формат ячейки 164. Но в нем же дата! Как так?

Каким образом я могу понять, что имею дело именно с датой?

**UPD:**

Я так же нашел строковое значение формата ячейки

```
string format = wbPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.Elements<NumberingFormat>()
            .Where(i => i.NumberFormatId.ToString() == cellFormat.NumberFormatId.ToString())
            .FirstOrDefault()?.FormatCode;
```

Для ячейки с датой это "dd/mm/yy\ h:mm;@". Но что с этим делать я не знаю. Не полагаться же на `Regex` в данном вопросе.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67648/discussion-on-question-by-irumba-openxml--).